# Use array to reference through array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(
      0 => array(
                 0 => array(
                            0 => array()
                 ),
                 1 => array(
                            1 => array()
                 )
      ),
      1 => array(
                 0 => array(
                            0 => array()
                 ),
                 1 => array(
                            1 => array()
                 )
      )
 )
```

*There may be a syntax error in that array but it's not important*

Then I have second array: `$pathArray = array(0 => 1, 1 => 0, 2 => 1)` which indicates a path (1,0,1) in the first array where my variable `$var = "test"`should be placed. So in the end it would look like:

```
array(
      0 => array(
                 0 => array(
                            0 => array()
                 ),
                 1 => array(
                            1 => array()
                 )
      ),
      1 => array(
                 0 => array(
                            0 => array()
                 ),
                 1 => array(
                            1 => array("test")
                 )
      )
 )
```

How can I do that? Hope it's clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$c = &$array;
for($i=0; $i<count($pathArray); $i++){
    $c = &$c[$pathArray[$i]]; 
}
$c[] = "test";
```

Comment: seems cool. Just one question: what does those `[]` stands for exactly in general?

Comment: [] means to add an element to the end of the array